# Implementing and generating multiple dynamic SiteMapNodes in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say I currently have this sitemap path:

```
<siteMapNode url="Home" title="Home" description="Home">

    <siteMapNode url="Shop" title="Shop" description="Shop" >

        <!-- There should be dynamic categories pages here -->

            <!-- There should be dynamic product names here -->

    </siteMapNode>

    <!-- Individual Pages -->
    <siteMapNode url="Login" title="Login"/>
    <siteMapNode url="TermsAndConditions" title="Terms And Conditions"/>
    <siteMapNode url="PrivacyPolicy" title="Privacy Policy"/>
    <siteMapNode url="ProhibitionsAndRestrictions" title="Prohibitions And Restrictions" />
    <siteMapNode url="ContactUs" title="Contact Us" />

</siteMapNode>
```

I don't have physical pages for my categories and products. There are all generated from query strings.

For example:

Category pages:

```
Shop?c=food
Shop?c=beverages
Shop?c=furniture
```

Product pages:

```
Product/fried-chicken-abc
Product/fried-rice-def
Product/herbal-tea-123
Product/wooden-chair-xyz
```

How can I have my categories and product pages be registered to my sitemap path dynamically?

I know you can do a `currentnodetemplate` for dynamic categories pages but what about the product pages? Since there are now **2** dynamic nodes (category & product)

Answer (score 1):

sitemap is a xml file. we can generate sitemap in c# . we should now tags and rules about this, then we can generate valid sitemap in c#.

first create a sitemap index. its a xml file. you can put this in your root of project and introduce that to search engine. it is a valid example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

<sitemap>

<loc>https://www.yourdomain.com/sitemap/coursesingle</loc>

<lastmod>2020-05-13T21:04:14+00:00</lastmod>

</sitemap>

<sitemap>

<loc>https://www.yourdomain.com/sitemap/videos</loc>

<lastmod>2020-05-13T21:04:14+00:00</lastmod>

</sitemap>

<sitemap>

<loc>https://www.yourdomain.com/sitemap/UserProfile</loc>

<lastmod>2020-05-13T21:04:14+00:00</lastmod>

</sitemap>

<sitemap>

<loc>https://www.yourdomain.com/sitemap/uppcategory</loc>

<lastmod>2020-05-13T21:04:14+00:00</lastmod>

</sitemap>

</sitemapindex>
```

add this code to model:

```
public enum SitemapFrequency

{

    Never,

    Yearly,

    Monthly,

    Weekly,

    Daily,

    Hourly,

    Always

}
```

add this class to model folder

```
public class SitemapNode

    {

        public SitemapFrequency? Frequency { get; set; }

        public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }

        public double? Priority { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }

    }
```

and these are namespaces. add theme to top of controller:

```
 private XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";

//xmlns:video=

private XNamespace xmlnsVideo = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1";
```

this is the action that we use in sitemapindex "coursesingle".

outputcache is for performance.

```
 [OutputCache(Duration = 43200, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)]// 6 saati ast 

    public ContentResult coursesingle()

    {

        var sitemapNodes = GetSingelCourseSitemapNodes();

        return getXmlSiteMapFromNodes(sitemapNodes.ToList());



    }
```

GetSingelCourseSitemapNodes:

```
private IReadOnlyCollection<SitemapNode> GetSingelCourseSitemapNodes()//UrlHelper urlHelper

    {

        List<SitemapNode> nodes = new List<SitemapNode>();

        var CourseNodes = db.Courses.ToList();



        foreach (var item in CourseNodes)

        {

            SitemapFrequency frequency = SitemapFrequency.Weekly;

            TimeSpan stabality = new TimeSpan();

            if (item.CourseLastModified != null)

            {

                stabality = (DateTime)item.CourseLastModified - (DateTime)item.CoursePublishDate;



                int days = (int)stabality.TotalDays;

                if (days > 30 && days < 300)

                    frequency = SitemapFrequency.Monthly;

                if (days > 300)

                    frequency = SitemapFrequency.Yearly;

            }

            else

            {



            }

            nodes.Add(

               new SitemapNode()

               {

                   Url = Url.Action("training", "mcourse", new { id = item.CourseID, FriendlyUrl = item.CourseSlug }, "https"),

                   Frequency = frequency,

                   Priority = item.CoursePriority,

                   LastModified = item.CourseLastModified

               });

        }

        return nodes;

    }
```

in getXmlSiteMapFromNodes we create the xml sitemap file:

```
 private ContentResult getXmlSiteMapFromNodes(List<SitemapNode> sitemapNodes)

    {

        XElement root = new XElement(xmlns + "urlset");

        foreach (SitemapNode sitemapNode in sitemapNodes)

        {

            XElement urlElement = new XElement(

                xmlns + "url",

                new XElement(xmlns + "loc", sitemapNode.Url),

                sitemapNode.LastModified == null ? null : new XElement(

                    xmlns + "lastmod",

                  MyDateTimeExtensions.ConvertDateTimeToString(sitemapNode.LastModified.Value)),

                sitemapNode.Frequency == null ? null : new XElement(

                    xmlns + "changefreq",

                    sitemapNode.Frequency.Value.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()),

                sitemapNode.Priority == null ? null : new XElement(

                    xmlns + "priority",

                    sitemapNode.Priority.Value.ToString("F1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

            root.Add(urlElement);

        }

        XDocument document = new XDocument(root);

        return Content("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" + document.ToString(), "text/xml", Encoding.UTF8);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The article below nicely describes how to create a dynamic SiteMap (e.g. url parameters from data retrieved from a database) as well as how to dynamically expose it both in a Web Forms and an MVC application.

I've implemented it in my own projects and it really works very well.

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/291/seo-for-asp-net-web-sites-getting-content-indexed